# Error in mapPropsToState upon clicking react-router Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have been trying to learn redux, by building a simple blog.

Everything seemed to be going pretty well, until I used a react-router `Link` component to use a blog title in blog list page to navigate to blog detail page.

So, I have the following react routes:

1. Root (/)
2. Show Post (/posts/:id)

If I go to each of the routes by entering them in the browser, it works fine.

However, the issue is when I am in the root page, and then I click a link to go to blog post detail path.

Here's my redux state:

```
import {
  FETCH_POST_LIST_REQUEST,
  FETCH_POST_LIST_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_POST_LIST_ERROR,
  FETCH_POST_REQUEST,
  FETCH_POST_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_POST_ERROR,
  CREATE_POST_REQUEST,
  CREATE_POST_SUCCESS,
  CREATE_POST_ERROR
} from '../constants'

const initialState = {
  postsList: {
    data: { collection: [] },
    isLoading: false
  },
  newPost: {
    data: {},
    isLoading: false
  },
  post: {
    data: {},
    isLoading: false
  }
}

const posts = function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case FETCH_POST_LIST_REQUEST:
    return {
      postsList: { data: { collection: [] }, isLoading: true }
    }
  case FETCH_POST_LIST_SUCCESS:
    return {
      postsList: { data: action.data, isLoading: false }
    }
  case FETCH_POST_LIST_ERROR:
    return {
      postsList: { data: [], isLoading: false }
    }
  case FETCH_POST_REQUEST:
    return {
      post: { data: {}, isLoading: true }
    }
  case FETCH_POST_SUCCESS:
    return {
      post: { data: action.data, isLoading: false }
    }
  case FETCH_POST_ERROR:
    return {
      post: { data: {}, isLoading: false }
    }
  case CREATE_POST_REQUEST:
    return {
      newPost: { data: {}, isLoading: true }
    }
  case CREATE_POST_SUCCESS:
    return {
      newPost: { data: action.data, isLoading: false }
    }
  case CREATE_POST_ERROR:
    return {
      newPost: { data: {}, isLoading: false }
    }
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

I was also able to figure out why I was getting the error.

When I am in root path, my redux state is `posts: { postsList: ... }`

When I directly go to a show path, my redux state changes to `posts: { post: ... }`

When I click the `Link`, it i supposed to route me to `/posts/1`, and render the following container:

```
import PostShow from '../components/post-show'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import * as actionCreators from '../actions'

const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {
    data: state.posts.post.data,
    isLoading: state.posts.post.isLoading
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostShow)
```

This container is connected to the following component:

```
import React from 'react'

class PostShow extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.actions.fetchPost(this.props.id)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
            this.props.isLoading ?
            'Loading...' :
            (
             <div className="post">
              <p className="title">{this.props.data.title}</p>
              <p className="content">{this.props.data.content}</p>
              <p className="author">{this.props.data.author}</p>
            </div>
            )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default PostShow
```

Upon transition from root path to show path, via clicking the react-router link, in the following code:

```
const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {
    data: state.posts.post.data,
    isLoading: state.posts.post.isLoading
  }
}
```

The redux state is still `posts: { postsList: ... }`, instead of `posts: { post: ... }`, which causes error at `state.posts.post.data`, causing the container to throw error.

The way I am doing things, the state is changed only after a store dispatch is triggered in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.actions.fetchPost(this.props.id)
}
```

I guess I am either doing things the wrong way, or missing something.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your reducer a bit,

```
const posts = function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case FETCH_POST_LIST_REQUEST:
    return {
      ...state,
      postsList: { data: { collection: [] }, isLoading: true }
    }
  case FETCH_POST_LIST_SUCCESS:
    return {
      ...state,
      postsList: { data: action.data, isLoading: false }
    }
  case FETCH_POST_LIST_ERROR:
    return {
      ...state,
      postsList: { data: [], isLoading: false }
    }
  case FETCH_POST_REQUEST:
    return {
      ...state,
      post: { data: {}, isLoading: true }
    }
  case FETCH_POST_SUCCESS:
    return {
      ...state,
      post: { data: action.data, isLoading: false }
    }
  case FETCH_POST_ERROR:
    return {
      ...state,
      post: { data: {}, isLoading: false }
    }
  case CREATE_POST_REQUEST:
    return {
      ...state,
      newPost: { data: {}, isLoading: true }
    }
  case CREATE_POST_SUCCESS:
    return {
      ...state,
      newPost: { data: action.data, isLoading: false }
    }
  case CREATE_POST_ERROR:
    return {
      ...state,
      newPost: { data: {}, isLoading: false }
    }
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

have a look here: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html

Comment: Bravo! Thank you so much! I was missing a very basic tenet of Redux, and modifying the state tree. The way I was doing it, it was yanking out the keys "post", "newPost". Thank you so much!